# How to get each item of a list as a line when extracting value from xml in oracle?

Tags: xml, oracle

I need to extract some values from a clob containing xml but it contains lists. 
My problem is that the extract command seems to either select one, or concat the list.

**How to get a duplication of the line for each item of my xml list ?**

I've looked in oracle extract documentation and they only propose to use a [1] indicator. From that, I can add columns to get the data, and then reselect to take all the columns into one, but the trick is I don't know how many items there is in the line. There might be a solution in PL/SQL but i'd like to avoid it if there is an easier solution.

```
CREATE TABLE collect_test (
    id         NUMBER,
    xml_data   XMLTYPE
);

               INSERT INTO collect_test VALUES 
   (       100, XMLType(
              '<Warehouse whNo="100"> 
              <Buildings>
               <Building>Owned</Building>
               <Building>Owned</Building>
               </Buildings>
               </Warehouse>'));
SELECT 
  w.id,
  w.xml_data.extract('/Warehouse/Buildings/Building/text()').getStringVal()
     "Building"
  FROM collect_test w;
```

The result is

> '100','OwnedOwned'

What I want is

> '100', 'Owned'
>
> '100', 'Owned'

Is there an easy way to achieve this ? I do not have control over the xml input. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/XMLTABLE.html):

```
SELECT 
  w.id,
  x.building
FROM collect_test w
CROSS JOIN xmltable (
  '/Warehouse/Buildings/Building'
  PASSING w.xml_data
  COLUMNS building VARCHAR2(30) PATH '.'
) x;

        ID BUILDING                      
---------- ------------------------------
       100 Owned                         
       100 Owned
```

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html).